# Access dll in linux

Tags: shared-library, mono

Okay so I have a bunch of `.dll` files that are compiled on windows (though I could recompile them on linux if that was necessary) that I want to use.

The final idea I am having is to write a `.so` that will be able to call the functions defined in the `dll`s.

As far as I have read this should be possible by using `mono` but I just can't seem to find any resource on how that might actually work. And by that I mean a specific example demonstrating the basics.

So let's assume I have a `.dll` that contains a function called `getText()` that will return the String `"Hello World"` when called.
How can I write my C++ code (I want it to be compiled to a `.so` so that's what I have to use, right?) that it calls that function and prints the returned String to the console? Is this even possible?

If the above scenario isn't possible: How can I use mono in general to access `dll`s? I have already written a C# example that does the job but ultimately I need a `.so` so this is not an option. Might there be some way to use mono from the command line to execute the function?

---

Another thing I found is the [loadlibrary](https://github.com/taviso/loadlibrary) framework which seems to be capable of what I am looking for. However I have no clue how I would use it, so I'd appreciate a little code-example

Comment: the loadlibrary framework site has an example `mpscript.c`  ....  looks like the dll file has to be copied from windows to the `engine` sub-directory ...... just read the whole webpage  ..... https://github.com/taviso/loadlibrary

Comment: If I understand correctly, linux cannot use `dll` files directly, but it works (with some dll files and in general with some Windows programs) with the interface program `wine`. See [www.winehq.org - What is Wine?](https://www.winehq.org/). Another 'almost' alternative is [CygWin](https://www.cygwin.com).

Comment: @jsotola thanks for pointing me to the website. I'll habe a look at this.

Comment: @sudodus for my specific case I don't think that wine is an option but I'll have a look at CygWin